# Proof of graph theorem using induction

Tags: graph-theory, induction

The question:

> Prove that every simple planar $G=(V,E)$ when $|V|\ge3$ has
>   a partition of $V$ into $3$ groups  $V=V_1 ⊍ V_2 ⊍ V_3$ (Foreign union in pairs) so that for every $i$ between $1$ and $3$, the sub-graph induced by $V_i$ has no cycles.

I tried to solve by induction but got stuck on the inductive step and I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For the inductive step, every simple, planar graph has a vertex $v$ of degree at most $5$. Using the induction hypothesis you can partition $G-v$ as desired. Why can you add $v$ to one of the vertex classes of the partition of $G-v$?

Comment: Thanks!  But why  every simple, planar graph has a vertex v of degree at most 5? This is a theorem?

Comment: From Euler's formula you can show that such a graph has at most $3n-6$ edges where $n$ is the number of vertices. By the Handshaking lemma the sum of the degrees is then at most $6n-12 < 6n$ so we can't have that every vertex has degree at least $6$

Comment: OK, got it ,but I still do not understand how to add the vertex in a way that does not create a circle.

Comment: Try supposing, for a contradiction, that adding $v$ to each of the $V_i$ creates a cycle (so that you can't do it). What can you say about the number of neighbours of $v$ in each $V_i$ and hence the number of neighbours of $v$ in total?

Comment: So v has at least 2 neighbours in each $V_i$ and at least 6 in total.  Contradiction! Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you got it.